# colorbox - close parent iframe and open new iframe lightbox

Tags: jquery, iframe, colorbox, parent-child

Im using jquery and colorbox lightbox plugin to open iframes in a ligthbox.

The problem is:

1. I click on button it opens my main iframe lightbox
2. inside the main iframe lightbox - there is button with class .flash_shareable
3. When you click, it should close the parent (i.e. main iframe) and then open a new iframe that it is linking to

It is closing the parent iframe, but its not opening the new iframe.

my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var y = $(document.body).height();
        var x = $(document).width();
        parent.$.colorbox.resize({innerWidth:x, innerHeight:y});

        $('.iframe').colorbox({iframe:true}); //ligthbox

        $(".flash_shareable").click(function() {
        parent.$.colorbox.close();
        $.colorbox({href:"faq.html", iframe:true, width:800 + "px", height:600 + "px", open:true});
    })
});
```

**HTML of iframe**, from which im trying to open another ligthbox:

```
<button class="flash_shareable" type="button">open flash</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it, but i still feel something is needed ^_^ **It does NOT work in Internet Explorer 8 and below**, I hope anyone can **help** me with that untill ? please :)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var y = $(document.body).height();
        var x = $(document).width();
        parent.$.colorbox.resize({innerWidth:x, innerHeight:y});

        $('.iframe').colorbox({iframe:true}); //ligthbox

        $(".flash_shareable").click(function() {

        $.colorbox({href:"faq.html", iframe:true, open:true});
    })
});
```

Comment: Try not to attach `colorbox` to an element, like the following:  `$.colorbox({iframe:true, href: yourUrl});`. And fix the missing `;` in the end of `click` function.

Comment: I just tested, it only works in Firefox n IE9, does not work in Chrome or IE8.